# angular material select and input inside the same field

Tags: angular, angular-material

I came across this post which works well when the select is after the input, but how would one use it with a mat-select before the matinput? As soon as I switch the order, the component becomes unusable, with the select being triggered with every click inside the field.

[Angular Material Input and select in one form field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54084852/angular-material-input-and-select-in-one-form-field)

My fork:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6nqzf1-ox413y?file=app%2Fform-field-overview-example.html

```
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
        <mat-label>End Time</mat-label>
        <mat-select name="ampm" class="ampm" [(ngModel)]="event.eampm">
            <mat-option value="AM">AM</mat-option>
            <mat-option value="PM">PM</mat-option>
        </mat-select>
        <input matInput type="time" placeholder="HH:MM" id="end_time_hour" [formControl]="timeFormControl">
   </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: The official way: https://material.angular.io/guide/creating-a-custom-form-field-control

Comment: Thanks, I'll accept this if you move the comment to an answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Follow the angular-material docs which looks at creating a custom form field control:  [Creating a custom form field control](http://creating%20a%20custom%20form%20field%20control)